# Condition in 75 times loop takes 17 sec in local

Tags: php, laravel

In a list of user, I have an avatar. When I write this:

```
<img src="{{ $user->avatar }}" class="img-circle img-sm"/></a>
```

Scripts take 17 sec for 75 users.

But when I write:

```
<img src="{{ "/images/avatar/avatar.png" }}" class="img-circle img-sm"/></a>
```

it goes pretty quick.

Why is this attribute so time consuming???

In this page, I call a lot of attribute from this object, but only this one is time consuming... It's just string more....

I'm in Laravel 5.3

EDIT: Paste full table:

```
<table class="table datatable-responsive" id="table{{ $championship->id }}">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="min-tablet text-center "
            data-hide="phone">{{ trans('core.avatar') }}</th>
        <th class="all">{{ trans('core.username') }}</th>
        <th class="phone">{{ trans('core.email') }}</th>
        <th align="center" class="phone">{{ trans_choice('categories.category',1) }}</th>
        <th align="center" class="phone">{{ trans('core.paid') }}</th>
        <th class="phone">{{ trans('core.country') }}</th>
        @can('edit',$tournament)
            <th class="all">{{ trans('core.action') }}</th>
        @endcan
    </tr>
    </thead>


    @foreach($championship->users as $user)
        <?php
        $arr_country = $countries->where('id', $user->country_id)->all();
        $country = array_first($arr_country, null);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                {{--<a href="{!!   URL::action('UserController@show',  $user->slug) !!}"><img--}}
                            {{--src="{{ is_null($user->avatar) ? "/images/avatar/avatar.png" : $user->avatar  }}" class="img-circle img-sm"/></a>--}}
            </td>
            <td>
                @can('edit',$user)
                    <a href="{!!   URL::action('UserController@edit',  ['users'=>$user->slug] ) !!}">{{ $user->name }}</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{!!   URL::action('UserController@show',  ['users'=>$user->slug] ) !!}">{{ $user->name }}</a>
                @endcan


            </td>
            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $championship->category->buildName($grades)}}</td>

            <td class="text-center">
                @if ($user->pivot->confirmed)
                    <?php $class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign text-success";?>
                @else
                    <?php $class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign text-danger ";?>
                @endif

                @can('edit',$tournament)
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'formConfirmTCU',
                'action' => ['CompetitorController@confirmUser', $tournament->slug, $championship->id,$user->slug  ]]) !!}


                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-flat btnConfirmTCU"
                            id="confirm_{!! $tournament->slug !!}_{!! $championship->id !!}_{!! $user->slug !!}"
                            data-tournament="{!! $tournament->slug !!}"
                            data-category="{!! $championship->id !!}"
                            data-user="{!! $user->slug !!}">
                        <i class="{!! $class  !!} "></i>
                    </button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                @else
                    <i class="{!! $class  !!} "></i>


                @endcan


            </td>


            <td class="text-center"><img src="/images/flags/{{ $country->flag }}"
                                         alt="{{ $country->name }}"/></td>

            @can('edit',$tournament)
                <td class="text-center">

                    {!! Form::model(null, ['method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'formDeleteTCU',
                 'action' => ['CompetitorController@deleteUser', $tournament->slug, $championship->id,$user->slug  ]]) !!}

                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn text-warning-600 btn-flat btnDeleteTCU"
                            id="delete_{!! $tournament->slug !!}_{!! $championship->id !!}_{!! $user->slug !!}"
                            data-tournament="{!! $tournament->slug !!}"
                            data-category="{!! $championship->id !!}"
                            data-user="{!! $user->slug !!}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                    </button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </td>
            @endcan
        </tr>

    @endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: How do you fetch the users and prepare the template?

Comment: Try this : `{{ is_null($user->avatar) ? "/images/avatar/avatar.png" : $user->avatar }}`. Other idea, perhaps avatar are big ?

Comment: @Zl3n same result

Comment: from index method. @foreach($championship->users as $user)... But really, I build attributes than are more complicated than this, and render quickly...

Comment: If you do a `var-dump` or `dd`of `$championship->users` object, how much time this takes ?

Comment: There has to be something else causing the slowdown. Do you have/use [Laravel Debugbar](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)? You can get the query information with it, might point to the problematic area. As a test, you could grab *just* the users (without going through the `championship` relationship) and iterate over them to test if the delay is still present.

Comment: already did that. Debugbar tell me query is OK, less than 1 sec for all. I commented element by element in my page, and this is the one which fails :( kind of weird ) I will parte my whole list to you can see all stuff

Comment: How big (and how fast) is the user class?

Comment: not so big, 20 attributes

Answer (score 0):

Is the `avatar` property a relationship to another table? It could be a lazy loading problem inside the `foreach`.

You can find more info about **lazy** and **eager** loading at [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: nop, avatar is an attribute of User. also I don't use lazy loading